# tooltip: exclude elements with a specific ID or class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jQueryUI tooltip on my site. I would like to give some objects on the page a class "noTooltip" to prevent the native ui element to be replaced. For example if you use CkEditor the tooltips will be a bit too obtrusive.
Actually I use this code to start the tooltip (it applies to the whole dom) and it is in the DOMReady jquery event:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

How do I add a ckeck if element has not the "noTooltip" class?

```
$(function() {
    $(document).not('.noTooltip').tooltip();
});
```

will have the result to remove the tooltip everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [items option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-items)

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).tooltip({
    items: ":not(.notooltip)"
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div title="t1">t1</div>
<div title="t2">t2</div>
<div title="t3" class="notooltip">t3</div>
<div title="t4">t4</div>
<div title="t5" class="notooltip">t5 <span title="x">span</span></div>
<div title="t6">t6 <span title="y">span</span></div>
```

Comment: I understand I should narrow down the selector (avoid using document selector) but as per my question this works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `.tooltip()` on the document.

Instead, select elements more specifically, and then filter them:

```
$(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').not('.noTooltip').tooltip()
});
```

Comment: but why .not() is not working on $(document) selector? (Just for my knowledge)

Comment: `.not()` filters out any elements in the current set. The only element in the current set is `document`. The recursive tooltip creation is handled within the `.tooltip()` plugin.

Comment: Ok! Got it! Thanks. This is then why @arun's answer works. He ckecsk for the class inside the tooltip()!.

Answer (score 0):

hasClass() method checks if any of the selected elements have a specified class name i.e noTooltip

For more info http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_hasclass.asp

Comment: I am looking for the opposite ;) If has NOT class. .not() will not apply. I have a very few items where the tooltip should not apply. Cannot mark those who should!

Comment: try using the if condition

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the tooltip on the document but on only the elments you want. So you can get all the elements with a title attributes that don't have the noTooltip class:

```
$(function() {
    $('[title]:not(.noTooltip)').tooltip();
});
```